# Error creating a new user (subscriber) in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a new user (subscriber) in Wordpress admin panel. I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_roles() in /chroot/home/test/test.com/html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/core/modules/strong-passwords/class-itsec-strong-passwords.php on line 52

Any one help me.

Comment: Ji upload your code

Comment: i did not add any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with the plugin and maybe with your current WordPress version. Deactivate the plugin and add the subscriber. Activate the plugin again. Otherwise, contact the plugin developers.

Comment: Ya i got answer